# Door won't latch or create tight seal after replacing weather stripping

Tags: doors, carpentry, weatherstripping

I have an interior french door that opens to an unconditioned enclosed porch.  I replaced weather stripping with the "platinum" rubber M-D "kerf" product from home depot.  It was previously the vinyl clad foam.

After replacing, door barely latches and gaps are more pronounced on the top and bottom of the latch side of the door.  It almost feels like the replacement weather stripping is too thick on the hinge side of the door.  If I apply strong, constant pressure, I can get the entire door to make contact with the weather stripping. Once I let go, the middle of the door where it's latched stays close to the jamb and sealed against stripping, but the top and bottom seem to be pulling away from the jamb.

I've tried tightening the hinges and they are all the way tight.  I can't get a crescent wrench around the door hinge pins to bend them since door trim is too bulky.

I've tried moving the strike toward the jamb, but once I tighten down screw it floats back to original position

Appreciate a solution for how to make the door latch properly and sit tight against the weather strip

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image: you can see daylight at top and bottom of latch side]

Comment: wrong size weather strip, to thick, vinyl clad is softer then rubber

Comment: Weatherstripping aside, the strike and latch aren't meeting up very well. (ie, the strike needs to be lower or the latch needs to be higher) One possibility is to run a 3" screw (or two) into one of the holes of the upper hinge into the jamb and the framing. This will bring the latch higher. The goal when tightening the screw(s) should be an even reveal all the way up the hinge side of the door.